# How do you get the unix timestamp for the start of today in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp

I realize that the current timestamp can be generated with the following...

```
var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```

What I'd like is the timestamp at the beginning of the current day.  For example the current timestamp is roughly `1314297250`, what I'd like to be able to generate is `1314230400` which is the beginning of today `August 25th 2011`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
var now = new Date();
var startOfDay = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var timestamp = startOfDay / 1000;
```

Comment: Milliseconds will always be `0` this way so `Math.floor` is superfluous I think.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Down.  The other answers seem good also, but as zzzz points out this is shorter and sweeter.

Comment: Looks like the third line should be: `var timestamp = startOfDay.getTime() / 1000`

Comment: @AdamC.: That would be fine but there's no need. `startOfDay` is automatically converted via [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9710267/96100.

Comment: returns undefined.

Comment: @VenkatKotra: No. `timestamp` contains the timestamp.

Answer (score 10):

Well, the cleanest and fastest way to do this is with:

```
long timestamp = 1314297250;
long beginOfDay = timestamp - (timestamp % 86400);
```

where 86400 is the number of seconds in one day

Comment: Looks clean, but doesn't work. If you're in GMT+2, the time you will get will be 02:00:00

Answer (score 4):

```
var now = new Date; // now

now.setHours(0);   // set hours to 0
now.setMinutes(0); // set minutes to 0
now.setSeconds(0); // set seconds to 0

var startOfDay = Math.floor(now / 1000); // divide by 1000, truncate milliseconds
```

Comment: Is the creation of all those objects really necessary? You can just set hours, minutes and seconds on `now`.

Comment: @Cristian Vrabie: Yes, you're correct. Not sure what I was thinking; thanks.

Comment: shotrer way now.setHours(0,0,0,0); // h , m ,s , ms

Answer (score 3):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
var t = d / 1000;
```

Comment: If milliseconds is set to `0`, then I don't think `Math.floor` adds much.

Comment: Indeed. I added it after seeing the other answer, but did not think much about it.

Comment: @Xeon06: Then, why don't you edit your answer and remove it, to not confuse others? :]

Answer (score 3):

Luis Fontes' solution returns **UTC time** so it can be 1 hour (daylight saving time) different from setHours solution.

```
var d = new Date();
var t = d - (d % 86400000);
```

Simplified version of examples above (**local time**).

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var t = d / 1000;
```

Here you can find some performance tests: http://jsperf.com/calc-start-of-day

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could subtract the modulo of a days length in miliseconds e.g.

```
var day = 24*60*60*1000;
var start_of_today = Date.now() - Date.now() % day;
```

Comment: Simple and fast. Love this one

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative for getting the beginning of the day is the following:

```
var now = new Date();
var beginningOfDay = new Date(now.getTime() -
                     now.getHours() * 60 * 60 * 1000 -
                     now.getMinutes() * 60 * 1000 -
                     now.getSeconds() * 1000 -
                     now.getMilliseconds());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest calculation to find the start time of the day from a given Unix timestamp:

`var startOfDay = timestamp - (timestamp % 86400);`

Comment: Why is this the simplest? How is it the best solution, explain this.

Comment: This does not require you to use any other package like Date. 
It uses mathematics to calculate the start time of the day.
Note: This is for GMT+0000. For local time zone, add the time difference accordingly.   



Example:  

Lets say we want the start time of `1709271062` 
`1709271062` is Fri Mar 01 2024 05:31:02 

`startOfDay=1709271062 - (1709271062 % 86400) = 1709251200`

`1709251200` is Fri Mar 01 2024 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
var yoursystemday = new Date(new Date().getTime()-(120000*60+new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60000));
yoursystemday = new Date();
var current_time_stamp = Math.round(yoursystemday.getTime()/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

For any date it's easy to get Timestamps of start/end of the date using ISO String of the date ('yyyy-mm-dd'):

```
var dateString = '2017-07-13';
var startDateTS = new Date(`${dateString}T00:00:00.000Z`).valueOf();
var endDateTS = new Date(`${dateString}T23:59:59.999Z`).valueOf();
```

To get ISO String of today you would use `(new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10)`
So to get TS for today:

```
var dateString = (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
var startDateTS = new Date(`${dateString}T00:00:00.000Z`).valueOf();
var endDateTS = new Date(`${dateString}T23:59:59.999Z`).valueOf();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date();
var startOfDay = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var timestamp = startOfDay.getTime() / 1000;
```