# In Javascript why do Date objects have both valueOf and getTime methods if they do the same?

Tags: javascript, date

MDN says that [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) and [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) are functionally equivalent. Why have two functions that do the very same thing?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The [`Date.prototype.getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z); it is unique to the Date type and an important method.

The [`Object.prototype.valueOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) is used to get the "primitive value" of any object and is used by the language internally when it needs to convert an object to a primitive.  For the Date class, it is convenient to use the "time" attribute (the value returned by `getTime()`) as its primitive form since it is a common representation for dates.  Moreover, it lets you use arithmetic operators on date objects so you can compare them simply by using comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, etc).

```javascript
var d = new Date();
d.getTime(); // => 1331759119227
d.valueOf(); // => 1331759119227
+d; // => 1331759119227 (implicitly calls "valueOf")
var d2 = new Date();
(d < d2); // => true (d came before d2)
```

Note that you could implement the "valueOf" method for your own types to do interesting things:

```javascript
function Person(name, age) {this.name=name; this.age=age;}
Person.prototype.valueOf = function() {return this.age; }

var youngster = new Person('Jimmy', 12);
var oldtimer = new Person('Hank', 73);
(youngster < oldtimer); // => true
youngster + oldtimer; // => 85
```

Comment: Be aware that `+d` is not the same as `0+d`. The latter converts Date to String.

Comment: I'm sure this is a prefectly good answer, but it's still a little fuzzy for me. Would you be able to elaborate a little? I'm confused by "get the 'primitive type'" and "time...as it's 'primitive form'". How is this a distinction between `getTime()` and `valueOf()`? ALso, what is meant by "scaled" representation? Thank you.

Comment: @Karl, the sole purpose of `getTime()` is to return the number of milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC. Whereas `valueOf()` returns a single value - it might be a string, a number but not an object class - hence primitive type. Something that might be used for comparisons, a numeric representation. I suppose the language designers thought you can already use `getTime()` for that purpose and just used it. It might have been implemented differently but for convenience they used `getTime()`.

Comment: Note that while `d < d2` will work, `d == d2` returns `false` for **any** `d`, `d2`. Therefore `d <= d2` and `d >= d2` will not treat equal values correctly. To properly compare equal values, you need to use either `d.valueOf() <= d2.valueOf()` or its `getTime` equivalent.

Comment: @jxg You are wrong in parts. _All_ relational operators (<, <=, >, >=) turn their operands to primitives and work fine with Date objects. The equality operators (===, !===, ==, !=) do not coerce, if both operands are objects, and thus fail to do what is intended. So it would indeed be possible to use `d <= d2 && d2 <= d` to compare for date equality. (Btw, to avoid bugs, _never_ use == and != in Javascript.)

Answer (score 26):

There are no difference in behaviour between those two functions:

[**v8 Source Code** on tag `4.8.47` in `/src/date.js`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/src/date.js&q=ValueOf&sq=package:v8&l=361):

```
// ECMA 262 - 15.9.5.8
function DateValueOf() {
  CHECK_DATE(this);
  return UTC_DATE_VALUE(this);
}
// ECMA 262 - 15.9.5.9
function DateGetTime() {
  CHECK_DATE(this);
  return UTC_DATE_VALUE(this);
}
```

But there are historical differences.

Answer (score 8):

[`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) is a method of all objects.  Objects are free to override this to be what they want.

Comment: This makes sense if we consider that getTime got introduced in JavaScript 1.0 and valueOf was introduced in JavaScript 1.1. My guess is that getTime was kept for backwards compability.