# date = new Date(); date.valueOf() vs Date.now()

Tags: javascript

I am getting started with JavaScript. I consulted my colleague on how to get the current time.

He told me with this code:

```
> date = new Date()
> date.valueOf()
```

But most people do it this way:

```
> Date.now()
```

The second method is simpler and more readable.

If I want to convince my colleague to use the second one, how should I explain the difference to him?

Comment: And what is his/her reason to use the first version?

Comment: Date.now() is not supported in IE8 , that's why some people avoid it

Comment: You can also do `(new Date()).valueOf()`.

Comment: @Sirko He also doesn't know.

Comment: The reason some people prefer `getTime()` is for consistency with `new Date("2020-11-22").getTime();` --and they have a point. It is easier to remember the default/no-args version of a function, than to remember a second function.

Comment: **See Also** [In Javascript why do Date objects have both valueOf and getTime methods if they do the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9710136/1366033)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are several ways to get the current time in JavaScript:

- [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) creates a `Date` object representing current date/time
- [`new Date().valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) returns number of milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC
- [`new Date().getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) Functionally equivalent to `new Date().valueOf()`
- [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) Functionally equivalent to the 2 methods above

As mentioned in the comments and MDN links, `Date.now()` is not supported in Internet Explorer 8. So if IE 8 compatibility is a concern you should use `new Date().valueOf()` at the cost of slightly diminished code readability.

Or if you want to use `Date.now()` but must be compatible with browsers which don't support it, you can place following code somewhere in your JavaScript files, which will add support for it.

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 46):

### 2019 answer

Since we no longer care about IE8, only two methods are interesting:

- [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) - creates a `Date` object representing the current date/time
- [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) - returns the number of milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC

<sub>(The other two methods mentioned in the older answers are functionally equivalent to `Date.now()` but look uglier and work in IE8.)</sub>

As a matter of style, I found it clearer to use `Date.now()` in code that deals with intervals (usually subtracting an earlier date from a later date to calculate the time elapsed), and `new Date()` for timestamps, e.g. those written to a database.

Answer (score 12):

I am usually using `+new Date()` or `+new Date().toString(36)` when I need timestamps.

Recently I changed to `Date.now()` because it is more efficient or will become one day more efficient.

Technically the OS reports the date time as a primitive, and by calling new `Date()` the JavaScript engine must create a object with prototypes (which is passed by reference, and must be garbage collected later), and then do another function call of `valueOf`.

However `Date.now` could be a static function of the global `Date` object, that does simple math on the value reported from the OS

I didn't check the source code of all JavaScript engines to make sure that `Date.now` doesn't create a date instance, but it is more efficient or will become one day more efficient.

EDIT
I checked quickjs and Date.now() is way more efficient

new Date()
https://github.com/bellard/quickjs/blob/master/quickjs.c#L42079

Date.now()
https://github.com/bellard/quickjs/blob/master/quickjs.c#L41996

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is the only one relevantly differentiating the alternatives.

Answer (score 11):

After reading MDN, it seems [`new Date().getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), [`new Date().valueof()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) and [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) are all functionally equivalent. *However*, `Date.now()` is only supported in browsers from different versions, most importantly IE9. So if pre IE9 support is important, you may need to polyfill.

Edit: really, the only concern is IE. Isn't it always? ;)