# How to calculate the difference between two datetimes ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Does anyone know how to calculate the difference between two datetimes in Javascript ?

For example: `2018-01-17T21:18:00` and `2018-01-16T21:17:00`

I tried to split them and add them together afterwards but I noticed the hours are already calculated in the date difference.

Why don´t people understand the simple difference between date and datetime ? Stop Voting down, or writing stuipid comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: @NikolaAndreev Date and DateTime - BIG difference

Comment: @Deadpool in which form do you want the result? The as datetime?

Comment: The best would be like 1 Day, 1 Hour and 1 Minute, but I can format it myself afterwards. :)

Comment: If you use Moment.js library it has lot of functions to do that already see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Math.abs` if you would get a negative value (ie if you don't know if `a` is lower then `b`)

Date object is essentially a number and you can do mathematical operations with it without getting timestamp

```js
var a = new Date('2018-01-17T21:18:00')
var b = new Date('2018-01-16T21:17:00')

console.log(a - b) // possible use
console.log(Math.abs(a - b)) // safe to use
console.log(Math.abs(b - a)) // safe to use
console.log(b - a) // not what you want
```

from there you just calculate how many days/hours/min there is

Comment: If you know for sure that `a` is bigger then `b` you don't need `Math.abs` (just do `a - b`)

Comment: oh ok, great thanks, I didn't expect it to be that simple

Comment: *Date object is essentially a number* — uhh, no, it's not. There's a `.valueOf()` function on its prototype that returns the same value as its `.getTime()` function, so that it works with arithmetic operators like a number, but it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use valueOf -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf

```js
let date1 = new Date('2018-01-17T21:18:00')
let date2 = new Date('2018-01-16T21:17:00')
//you get the difference in ms
let difference = Math.abs(date1.valueOf()-date2.valueOf())
//you can then convert to any format
```

Comment: You don't need to use `valueOf` thanks to `valueOf` existence [read differens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710136/in-javascript-why-do-date-objects-have-both-valueof-and-gettime-methods-if-they)